# Why can I not set my value object's property to 0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have this fluent configuration for my `ApplicationSettings` entity

```
builder.OwnsOne(
    applicationSettings => applicationSettings.ActivitySettings,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.Property(activitySettings => activitySettings.PastDaysAllowedThreshold)
            .HasColumnName("ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold")
            .HasDefaultValue(7);

        builder.HasCheckConstraint(
            "CK_ApplicationSettings_ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold",
            "ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold >= 0");
    });
```

Where `ActivitySettings` looks like this

```
public sealed class ActivitySettings // : ValueObject
{
    public ActivitySettings(int pastDaysAllowedThreshold)
    {
        EnsureArg.IsGte(pastDaysAllowedThreshold, 0, nameof(pastDaysAllowedThreshold));

        PastDaysAllowedThreshold = pastDaysAllowedThreshold;
    }

    public int PastDaysAllowedThreshold { get; } // already tried adding a setter.
}
```

And `ApplicationSettings` has this method

```
public void SetActivitySettings(ActivitySettings activitySettings)
{
    EnsureArg.IsNotNull(activitySettings, nameof(activitySettings));

    ActivitySettings = activitySettings;

    RaiseDomainEvent(new ActivitySettingsUpdated(Id, activitySettings));
}
```

Everything is working perfectly, except for when I set `PastDaysAllowedThreshold` to `0`. I can see that the tracked entity from the repo thinks that the value has been set to 0, but when I look in the database it has not changed.

What is going on

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by updating the config to

```
builder.OwnsOne(
    applicationSettings => applicationSettings.ActivitySettings,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.Property(activitySettings => activitySettings.PastDaysAllowedThreshold)
            .HasColumnName("ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold")
            .HasDefaultValue(7)
            .ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.HasCheckConstraint(
            "CK_ApplicationSettings_ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold",
            "ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold >= 0");
    });
```

Notice the addition of `ValueGeneratedNever()`

Before adding this, for some reason ef was generating this in my snapshot

```
b1.Property<int>("PastDaysAllowedThreshold")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()      // this was causing the issue
    .HasColumnType("int")
    .HasDefaultValue(7)                                      
    .HasColumnName("ActivityPastDaysAllowedThreshold");
```

And when profiling those queries when trying to set the value to 0, I could see that no SQL was being executed whatsoever.